# Can someone explain different nozzles?

Tags: vessel

I know you can get several different nozzles, but AFAIK, there are not obvious uses for them, nor the game really explains what to use them for, aside the small animation you get when making the upgrades in the workshop.

So, are all the nozzles really necessary to progress through the game? or you can make through it with just the standard nozzle?

I have already completed both the factory and the orchard, having every nozzle at level 1, and I don't remember if I really needed more than the standard nozzle. I used the "wide stream" nozzle several times, but I think it can just be replaced by the normal one.

As for the other three, one seems to spit a blob of just enough liquid to create a fluoro, is that right? the other seems to spit a seed, but you still need liquid for it, so what is it needed for? And the last one, seems to have some "recoil", but it is not even enough to hover like a jet-pack (at least in level 1), so whats the point?

Do they get used more in the next levels? Because the game really doesn't explain them or make them obvious in the journal.

Perhaps later in the game they do become necessary, and the same goes to upgrading them. The only level 2 upgrade I've gotten is for the containers but they are actually and obviously useful. The other upgrades for every nozzle just give more distance for "shooting", but that's about it.

Please tell me whats the purpose of those other nozzles, not only what they do, but examples of uses in the game. Just avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 5):

Having finished the game, I can tell you that those are simply some "nice to have" upgrades. None of them are actually necessary to finish the game. They can make some situations a bit easier, but that's all.

- The one which creates a fluoro ensures you use just what you need of liquid, it prevents wasting. It also allows you to actually propel a fluoro where you want.
- The big one is useful when you want to refill your container faster. It's also helping you to clear some areas (ie. lava belts) faster. Same goes for the one throwing orbs of liquid.
- The blowback nozzle allows you to hover a bit, but not much more, even fully upgraded. It can help preventing you from falling in some endless abyss, or in spikes, lava, though.

All in all, they are just giving you little helps, depending on the situation. But you can make it through the whole game with the initial nozzle, as far as I experienced.

Comment: Another use for the one that throws orbs of liquid is that that liquid is exactly the needed quantity to make a fluro out of a seed. So, it is similar to the one that makes fluros directly, but in this case you need a seed placed before. And regarding the "blowback" nozzle negating fall damage, i believe that is false, since the game does NOT have any damage from falling, regardless the distance. (in fact one achievement relies on that). The only way to die from falling, is if you fall in spikes, lava, etc, but never from falling in regular "ground".

Comment: @DiegoDD - indeed, I forgot that part. I corrected the answer. It can be helpful to prevent any hazard from falling in a place you don't want to, mostly.